# zip file issue using password

Tags: scripting, security, password, zip

I have a `.txt` file and I have a bash script where txt file will be zipped and moved to other sftp server.

I am using

```
zip -P pass foo.zip foo.txt
```

Here in the script the password is visible but I should not save the hard coded password over there . Can any one help me out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the `zip` man page,

```
-P password
       --password password
              Use  password  to encrypt zipfile entries (if any).  THIS IS INSECURE!  Many multi-user operating systems provide ways for any user to see the current command line of any other user; even
              on stand-alone systems there is always the threat of over-the-shoulder peeking.  Storing the plaintext password as part of a command line in an automated script is even  worse.   Whenever
              possible,  use the non-echoing, interactive prompt to enter passwords.  (And where security is truly important, use strong encryption such as Pretty Good Privacy instead of the relatively
              weak standard encryption provided by zipfile utilities.)
```

As it is mentioned in the man page, THIS IS HIGHLY INSECURE!

So, you can try the below, From the `zip` man page again,

```
--encrypt
              Encrypt the contents of the zip archive using a password which is entered on the terminal in response to a prompt (this will not be echoed; if standard error is not a tty, zip  will  exit
              with an error).  The password prompt is repeated to save the user from typing errors.
```

The command goes something like,

`zip --encrypt foo.zip foo.txt` which asks for password on terminal,

```
Enter password: 
Verify password: 
updating: foo.txt (stored 0%)
```

**WARNING:** The encryption used by `zip` is not really a strong one. It can be cracked easily!

Comment: but this will break the script?right?What to do for that?